# How can I get JSON data in Dev Express for charts?

Tags: json, devextreme

**I want to drop data with JSON in Devexpress charts, ı already get data ,
 but json dont consider function x()**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 

function x(dataSource){
                $("#container").dxChart({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    series: {
                        argumentField: "day",
                        valueField: "oranges",
                        name: "My oranges",
                        type: "bar",
                        color: '#ffa500'
                    }
                });
            }
            
            $.getJSON("data/simpleJSON.json", function (dataSource) {
               x(dataSource);
        });
});
```

```css
SIMPLE JSON :

  [{
       day: "Monday",
       oranges: 3
   }, {
       day: "Tuesday",
       oranges: 2
   }, {
       day: "Wednesday",
       oranges: 3
   }, {
       day: "Thursday",
       oranges: 4
   }, {
       day: "Friday",
       oranges: 6
   }, {
       day: "Saturday",
       oranges: 11
   }, {
       day: "Sunday",
       oranges: 4
   }]
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: How can I solve this problem? I got JSON data on page, but the function can not show it in page.

Comment: Are there any error messages? One possible issue could be that this function causes a livelock: in your function x you call the same function without any condition, causing this function to endlessy run as soon as you call this function. You should check fiddler is this is the case and if so, fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, JS elements must be in quotation marks ("...").

SIMPLE JSON :

[{
       "day": "Monday",
       "oranges": 3
   }, {
       "day": "Tuesday",
       "oranges": 2
   }, {
       "day": "Wednesday",
       "oranges": 3
   }, {
       "day": "Thursday",
       "oranges": 4
   }, {
       "day": "Friday",
       "oranges": 6
   }, {
       "day": "Saturday",
       "oranges": 11
   }, {
       "day": "Sunday",
       "oranges": 4
   }]